# Issue retrieving auth with Google API Client for Mac OS X app

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-api-client

I’m working on a Mac OS X app, where the user will need to access their Google Calendar. However, I can’t get the authentication to work and it doesn’t really make any sense to me why it’s not working.

Google API is installed via Cocoapods: pod ‘Google-API-Client/Calendar'

I’ve got a NSTabViewController inside a NSWindow, when a user clicks a button I called the following:

```
   @property (nonatomic, strong)GTMOAuth2WindowController *windowController;
    static NSString *const scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

    - (void)startAuthentication {

     GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth  =  [GTMOAuth2WindowController authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName 
clientID:kClientID clientSecret:kClientSecret];

     if ( auth.canAuthorize) {
             return;
     }

     self.windowController = [[GTMOAuth2WindowController alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                    clientID:kClientID
                                                                clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                            keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                              resourceBundle:nil];
     }

     - (void)windowController:(GTMOAuth2WindowController *)windowController
        finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error {}
```

Don’t know why, but the selector is never called. From debug I noticed the Fetcher starts, and kGTMOAuth2UserSignedIn gets posted, but it never ends.

Any ideas why this isn’t working?

Answer (score 0):

Had nothing to do with the Google code, it was an issue with the window containing the viewController.